# 530 error when trying to open FTP directory

Tags: web-scraping, ftp, scrapy

I want to use Scrapy to download files and navigate folders at `ftp://ftp.co.palm-beach.fl.us/Building%20Permits/`.

Here's my spider:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request

class LatestPermitsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name=           "latest_permits"
    allowed_domains=["ftp.co.palm-beach.fl.us"]
    handle_httpstatus_list = [404]

    ftpUser=        "the_username"
    ftpPW=          "the_password"
    permitFilesDir= "ftp://ftp.co.palm-beach.fl.us/Building%20Permits/"

    def start_requests(self):
        yield Request(
            url=self.permitFilesDir,
            meta={
                "ftp_user": self.ftpUser,
                "ftp_password": self.ftpPW
            }
        )

    def parse(self,response):
        print response.body
```

When I run `scrapy crawl latest_permits`, I get this error:

```
ConnectionLost: ('FTP connection lost', <twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.protocols.ftp.CommandFailed: ['530 Sorry, no ANONYMOUS access allowed.']>)
```

Why does this error come up even when I supply the correct username and password?

Comment: because that's not how you pass username and password to an FTP. Connect using the old school `protocol://username:password@host:port` URL format instead.

Comment: I do not know the host and port for the FTP I want to access

Comment: The host is `ftp.co.palm-beach.fl.us`

Comment: of course you do. You're accessing `ftp://ftp.co.palm-beach.fl.us/Building%20Permits/` so the correct way to log into that FTP is by using `ftp://the_username:the_password@ftp.co.palm-beach.fl.us/Building%20Permits/"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the below source code of scrapy

https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/ftp.py

The issue is not with your `username` or `password`. The issue is the `scrapy` supports only `files` to be downloaded using `ftp` it doesn't add support for listing directories. The url you are using is a directory url

There is a possible workaround to actually use a package name `ftptree`

Add `handlers.py` with below code

```
import json

from twisted.protocols.ftp import FTPFileListProtocol

from scrapy.http import Response
from scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.ftp import FTPDownloadHandler

class FtpListingHandler(FTPDownloadHandler):
    def gotClient(self, client, request, filepath):
        self.client = client
        protocol = FTPFileListProtocol()
        return client.list(filepath, protocol).addCallbacks(
            callback=self._build_response, callbackArgs=(request, protocol),
            errback=self._failed, errbackArgs=(request,))

    def _build_response(self, result, request, protocol):
        self.result = result
        body = json.dumps(protocol.files)
        return Response(url=request.url, status=200, body=body)
```

And then in your `settings.py` use

```
DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS = {'ftp': 'cralwername.handlers.FtpListingHandler'}
```

A sample spider

```
import os
import json
from urlparse import urlparse

from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.http.request import Request

from ftptree_crawler.items import FtpTreeLeaf

class AnonFtpRequest(Request):
    anon_meta = {'ftp_user': 'anonymous',
                 'ftp_password': 'laserson@cloudera.com'}

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AnonFtpRequest, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.meta.update(self.anon_meta)


class FtpTreeSpider(Spider):
    name = 'ftptree'

    def __init__(self, config_file, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FtpTreeSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        with open(config_file, 'r') as ip:
            config = json.loads(ip.read())
        url = 'ftp://%s/%s' % (config['host'], config['root_path'])
        self.start_url = url
        self.site_id = config['id']

    def start_requests(self):
        yield AnonFtpRequest(self.start_url)

    def parse(self, response):
        url = urlparse(response.url)
        basepath = url.path
        files = json.loads(response.body)
        for f in files:
            if f['filetype'] == 'd':
                path = os.path.join(response.url, f['filename'])
                request = AnonFtpRequest(path)
                yield request
            if f['filetype'] == '-':
                path = os.path.join(basepath, f['filename'])
                result = FtpTreeLeaf(
                    filename=f['filename'], path=path, size=f['size'])
                yield result
```

Links to look at if you need further information

https://github.com/laserson/ftptree/blob/master/ftptree_crawler/

https://gearheart.io/blog/crawling-ftp-server-with-scrapy/